# fortran 1.0D0, D0 required or compile fail

Tags: fortran, gfortran

[NOTE: contains repetition of previous question but posted separately as separate issues]

I am compiling a program which is known to compile with ifort using gfortran. However the compiler fails on the line

```
IF (IANG.NE.0) IANG=IANG*SIGN(1.0,XX(4))
```

with the compile error:

```
make: *** [main_file.o] Error 1
```

Changing this line to (note D0)

```
IF (IANG.NE.0) IANG=IANG*SIGN(1.0D0,XX(4))
```

solves the problem

The compiler flags are:

```
gfortran -fno-automatic -mcmodel=medium -O2 -ffast-math  main_file.o -o main_file
```

Even an explanation for this behaviour would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Derek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the compilation error is likely to be a mismatch between the type+kind of `1.0` and `XX(4)`, the Fortran standard requires that the arguments to `SIGN` match in both kind and type.  Since you haven't shown us the declaration of the array `XX` I feel confident in asserting that it is probably declared to be `real` with `kind=kind(1.0d0)`.

Comment: Hi again! Thank you, this appears to be correct. The declaration of XX(4) states: DOUBLE PRECISION XX(6)